# Mysite not working

Tags: 2013, mysite

I am totally New to this mysite concept and followed one article to create mysite. When i open mysite i still get this Message

```
While we set things up, feel free to change your photo, adjust your personal settings, and fill in information about yourself.

It could take us a while, but once we're done, here's what you'll get:
Newsfeed is your social hub where you'll see updates from the people, documents, sites, and tags you're following, with quick access to the apps you've added.
OneDrive for Business is your personal hard drive in the cloud, the place you can store, share, and sync your work files.
Sites gives you easy access to the places you'll want to go.
```

Does anyone what can i do to get rid of this? I cannot see blog section in it.

Comment: MySites get batched for creation, therefore you may well see a delay while your MySite is created. If this continues for an extended period of time however there may be an issue. Check that self service site creation is enabled for the MySite web application to ensure that users are allowed to create MySites.

Comment: @AndyDawson its been 1 day now. Where to check for self service site creation is enabled or not?

Comment: @AndyDawson its enabled i checked

Comment: Which article did you follow?  Could you post the link?  It might help provide insight.

Comment: Can you check that the appropriate managed path has been created for MySites within the MySite web application? This is typically 'Personal' as a wildcard managed path.

Comment: @CorneliusJ.vanDyk i followed this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-configure-sharepoint-2013-my-site/

Comment: i mananged now by following this link http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/25/visual-guide-setting-up-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE yes after i refered another link which i mentioned in my comment above Yours.

Answer (score 0):

Please go into the User Profile Service Application in Central Administration. Go to Manage User Profiles. Search for your profile. Modify the "Personal Site Capabilities" from the existing value to 14. Save the profile and wait a few minutes, then re-check your MySite.